# Pauli exclusion principle and antimatter

Tags: experimental-physics, antimatter, pauli-exclusion-principle

Have the Pauli exclusion principle been proven to apply to antimatter experimentally?

Comment: see this "putting the Pauli exclusion pincipeple to test" https://cerncourier.com/a/putting-the-pauli-exclusion-principle-on-trial/. If you read the last paragraph you will see the complication of the experimental tests that certainly cannot be performed with positrons and antiprotons at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While CERN has [created anti-hydrogen](https://home.cern/news/press-release/cern/first-atoms-antimatter-produced-cern), there has never been a synthesized multi-antielectron anti-atom. So there has never been a large enough anti-atom (antinucleons with antielectrons) to *experimentally* test the PEP for antimatter.

But the Pauli exclusion principle applies to all spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles (all fermions) and one would be *shocked* that in anti-atoms containing several anti-electrons,  the PEP was not obeyed.

Comment: It could make for some interesting chemistry if PEP didn't apply for multi-electron AM atoms!